# Create dataframe from series in nested dictionnaries time series python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, regression

So i've got a dict with multiple nested dicts.

Each nested dicts corresponds to some parameters from a rolling window regression

The first level of the dictionnary corresponds to all the variables I regressed :

```
Keys  Type   Size
Var1  Dict    2      'params' : Dataframe, 'r_sq' : series
Var2  Dict    2      'params' : Dataframe, 'r_sq' : series
Var3  Dict    2      'params' : Dataframe, 'r_sq' : series
Var4  Dict    2      'params' : Dataframe, 'r_sq' : series
Var5  Dict    2      'params' : Dataframe, 'r_sq' : series
Var6  Dict    2      'params' : Dataframe, 'r_sq' : series
Var1  Dict    2      'params' : Dataframe, 'r_sq' : series
```

There is a nested dict for all the variables. In the nested dict, I have one serie (r_sq) and one dataframe (constant & coef).

It goes like this for all the variables (Var1 to Varn):

```
Keys        Type      Size
Params    dataframe   4580,2
r_sq       series     4580
```

further, when I enter each or the series & df, it displays like this:

r_sq:

```
Date          0
2008-01-01   0.8384
2008-01-02   0.9487
2008-01-03   0.4738
2008-01-04   0.7348
2008-01-05   0.3743
2008-01-06   0.8483
...          ...
```

params (the example is for the var1, each coefficients column in the params dataframes are named after the respective variable of the inital) :

```
Date         const       var1
2008-01-01   0.8384      0.4545
2008-01-02   0.9487      0.4845
2008-01-03   0.4738      0.5849
2008-01-04   0.7348      0.7438
2008-01-05   0.3743      0.3478
2008-01-06   0.8483      0.4738
...          ...         ...
```

The r_sq series and params df goes from 2008 to 2021 and contain 4580 observations each.

The structure of the Dict is as following :

```
data1 = {'var1':{
                    'params': 'dataframe',
                    'r_sq': 'series'
                    }
         'var2':{
                    'params': 'dataframe',
                    'r_sq': 'series'
                    }
                     }
         'var3':{
                    'params': 'dataframe',
                    'r_sq': 'series'
                    }
           ...
                     }
         'var24':{
                    'params': 'dataframe',
                    'r_sq': 'series'
                    }
       }
```

the names of all the nested dicts are the names of the variables.

So what i'd like to do here is to contatenate values and create 3 DF:

- One for the r_sq series
- One for the constant serie
- One for the coeffient serie

so it could look something like this :

```
df1
Date        r_sq.key1   r_sq.key2  r_sq.key3 ... r_sq.key 24
2008-01-01   0.8384      0.4545      0.8483      0.4738
2008-01-02   0.9487      0.4845      0.8483      0.4738
2008-01-03   0.4738      0.5849      0.8483      0.4738
2008-01-04   0.7348      0.7438      0.8483      0.4738
2008-01-05   0.3743      0.3478      0.8483      0.4738
2008-01-06   0.8483      0.4738      0.8483      0.4738
...
2021-01-22   0.8483      0.8483      0.8483      0.8483

df2
Date        coef.key1   coef.key2  coef.key3 ... coef.key 24
2008-01-01   0.8384      0.4545      0.8483        0.4738
2008-01-02   0.9487      0.4845      0.8483        0.4738
2008-01-03   0.4738      0.5849      0.8483        0.4738
2008-01-04   0.7348      0.7438      0.8483        0.4738
2008-01-05   0.3743      0.3478      0.8483        0.4738
2008-01-06   0.8483      0.4738      0.8483        0.4738
...
2021-01-22   0.8483      0.8483      0.8483        0.8483

df3
Date        const.key1   const.key2  const.key3 ... const.key 24
2008-01-01   0.8384      0.4545      0.8483          0.4738
2008-01-02   0.9487      0.4845      0.8483          0.4738
2008-01-03   0.4738      0.5849      0.8483          0.4738
2008-01-04   0.7348      0.7438      0.8483          0.4738
2008-01-05   0.3743      0.3478      0.8483          0.4738
2008-01-06   0.8483      0.4738      0.8483          0.4738
...
2021-01-22   0.8483      0.8483      0.8483        0.8483
```

I'm new to python, so any help you can provide would be super helpfull.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide the actual structure of the main dictionary? Is it something like this? nested={'Var1':{'params' : dataframe, 'r_sq' : series},'Var2':{'params' : dataframe, 'r_sq' : series}} ? Also, you want to concat all dataframes into one dataframe, right?

Comment: Yes I provided the structure of the main dict. I also provided an example of the outputs df i would like to contatenate